# Whу can't one say "dieses ist ein Auto"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

If there are so many demonstrative pronouns in German, what is the point of using *"das"* in a sentence like *"Das ist ein Auto."?* Why don't we just say *"Dieses ist ein Auto."?*

Intuitively I know that it would be incorrect to say *"Dieses ist ein Auto",* but I need someone to explain me this from the grammar point of view.

Why should one say *"das ist ein/eine",* instead of *"dieses/diese/dieser ist ein/eine ..."?* Is it something about the sentence structure?

Comment: Well, I mean, you can, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: What's the context? I guess "dieses ist ein Auto" is fine where "this one's a car" works in English.

Comment: While "dieses ist ein Auto" doesn't sound very good in german, you could absolutely use "dies ist ein Auto" or alternatively just "dieses Auto". Depending on how you want to use it, in what kind of sentence and so on. Sadly I'm not wellversed enough with why it's used right now so I can't give a proper answer.

Comment: @Trae: "Was sind das für Fahrzeuge?" - "Dieses ist ein Auto, jenes ein Fahrrad, ..."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Absolutely correct technically speaking, but I have never heard anyone use it either. I commonly hear "Das ist ein, das ist ein Fahrrad, das ist ein E-Scooter". I made it a comment not an answer, because I don't think it sounds very good and I don't really hear or see it used much.

Comment: @Trae: Absolutely correct; in spoken/less formal German, "dieses" and "jenes" are rarely used and normally get replaced with "das hier"/"das da".

Answer (score 2):

Hubert Schölnast has nicely explained the use of demonstrative pronouns.

However, I do not think that the phrase "Dieses ist ein Auto" is wrong. Yes, it is perhaps an unusul formulation and in most cases "Das ist ein Auto" should be preferred, but in a certain context I would nevertheless use it.

For example, on a parking lot I could point to a car and say "Dieses ist mein Auto". Of course, "Das ist mein  Auto" would also do and most people would use this phrase. But "dieser / diese / dieses" has more emphasis than "der / die / das" and therefore it can be used correctly if one wants to identify a certain object in a collection of things or just to put special emphasis to something.

An example from the bible is *Matthäus 3.17*:

> Dieser ist mein lieber Sohn, an dem ich Wohlgefallen habe. [Elberfelder Bibel]

But I have to admit that there other translations like

> Das ist mein geliebter Sohn, an dem ich Wohlgefallen habe. [Zürcher Bibel]

> Dies ist mein lieber Sohn, an dem ich Wohlgefallen habe. [Lutherbibel 2017]

See [here](https://www.bibleserver.com/ZB/Matth%C3%A4us3%2C17).

Answer (score 1):

Demonstrative pronouns are not really freely interchangeable.

- **dieser, diese, dieses**
  You use these demonstrative pronouns if you use it as an attribute of a noun, and you use it to describe something that is close to you:

  > Masculine: **Dieser** Wagen ist alt.
  > Feminine: **Diese** Karre ist alt.
  > Neuter: **Dieses** Auto ist alt.
- **jener, jene, jenes**
  Same as before, but for things that are far away from the speaker:

  > Masculine: **Jener** Wagen ist alt.
  > Feminine: **Jene** Karre ist alt.
  > Neuter: **Jenes** Auto ist alt.
- **der, die, das**
  You can use them independent from the distance, and you also can use them as attributes, but when you do so, they often will be interpreted as articles instead of pronouns:

  > Masculine: **Der** Wagen ist alt.
  > Feminine: **Die** Karre ist alt.
  > Neuter: **Das** Auto ist alt.

  But there is an alternative usage (substantival use, see the [distinction in DWDS](https://dwds.de/wb/das#2)), where you can use the pronoun alone as subject (also as object, but I show subjects in my examples)

  > Masculine: **Der** ist alt.
  > Feminine: **Die** ist alt.
  > Neuter: **Das** ist alt.
- **dies**
  This demonstrative pronoun is for substantival usage for things close to you:

  > M: **Dies** ist der Wagen meiner Schwester.
  > F: **Dies** ist die Karre meiner Schwester.
  > N: **Dies** ist das Auto meiner Schwester.
- **jenes**
  Like *"dies",* but for things far away from the speaker, but this version is rarely used:

  > M: **Jenes** ist der Wagen meiner Schwester.
  > F: **Jenes** ist die Karre meiner Schwester.
  > N: **Jenes** ist das Auto meiner Schwester.
- **das**
  This is the distance-independent version for substantival use:

  > M: **Das** ist der Wagen meiner Schwester.
  > F: **Das** ist die Karre meiner Schwester.
  > N: **Das** ist das Auto meiner Schwester.

And of course all these pronouns have different forms in different grammatical cases, and they all also have a plural form.

---

So, when you say

> *wrong:* **Dieses** ist ein Auto.

Then you use a pronoun that should used as an attribute in an substantival manner. For substantival usage you can use:

> *correct:* **Das** ist ein Auto. (best choice)
> *correct:* **Dies** ist ein Auto. (also fine, but only if it's close to you)
> *correct:* **Jenes** ist ein Auto. (rarely used, only correct if it's far away. The better version is *"das".*)

Comment: "Dieses ist ein Auto" is correct if you want to identify a car in a set of vehicles. See the above comments by DonHolgo and O. R. Mapper.

Comment: What do you mean by adverbial usage?

Comment: @МаргоБессмертных: Attributive: The word accompanies a noun. Adverbial: The word accompanies a verb. If it it used attributive it is part of a noun phrase. If it is used adverbial it is part of the predicate as defined in German grammar. (English grammar and German grammar have different definitions of predicates. For details please consult [*Prädikat* in German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prädikat_(Grammatik)))

Comment: @KritikerderElche: You are right. Please can you write an answer to explain how and why?

Comment: I'm still confused by "adverbial use". "Das" is a Demonstrativ**pronomen** here, so it stands for a noun. It's the subject of the sentence in "Das ist ein Auto". It is not an adjective. So if I'm not mistaken there should be no attributive use and no adverbial use. What about "Das mag ich nicht.", where "das" is an accusative object? Are you saying "das" is adverbial there, too?

Comment: @HalvarF: Sorry, this is just one half of the truth. The other half is represented by usages like *»**Diese** Rose it rot.«* Here the pronoun does **not** stand for a noun. Here it is a word that describes a noun and it is used together with the noun in a nominal phrase. And this defines the pronoun as an **attribute** of a noun, not as a placeholder.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: I totally agree about "diese Rose", but "Das ist ein Auto." and "Das ist der Wagen meiner Schwester." and "Dies ist die Karre meiner Schwester." are your examples for what you call "adverbial usage".

Comment: After looking it up: DWDS calls "Dies ist ein Auto" "substantivisch" in contrast zu "Dieses Auto gehört Julia" which they call "adjektivisch": https://dwds.de/wb/dieses https://dwds.de/wb/das#2 Which makes more sense to me. "Substantivisch" and "adverbial" obviously exclude each other.

Comment: -1 weil (wieder mal) keine Reaktion auf Hinweise in den Kommentaren auf Fehler. Ich verstehe es nicht -- ist doch kein großes Ding, das zu korrigieren, im Verhältnis zu dem Aufwand, diesen Betrag zu schreiben.

Comment: @HalvarF: Ich verstehe dich nicht ganz. Du hast schon fast 10.000 Reputationspunkte, kannst also schon seit einer halben Ewigkeit Fehler in anderen Postings ausbessern, und anstatt es zu tun diskutierst du tagelang und wertest das Posting ab das du besser machen könntest. - ist doch kein großes Ding, das zu korrigieren, im Verhältnis zu dem Aufwand, hier diese Kommentare zu schreiben.

Comment: OK, mein Eindruck aus der Zeit, in der ich hier bin, ist bisher nicht, dass es hier üblich oder gewünscht ist, anderer Leute Antworten über Tippfehler hinaus zu korrigieren, aber wenn du damit kein Problem hast, kann ich es in Zukunft auch so machen.

Comment: Wenn du inhaltliche Korrekturen und Ergänzungen von anderen erwartest, solltest du deine Beiträge als community wiki veröffentlichen.

Comment: Non-fluent speakers should be told not to use "jener" ever. The DWDS qualifies it as "feierlich". In spoken discourse it just sounds wrong.